# Canel the drag event in DualList when a record is moved in GXT

Tags: gxt

I want to cancel an event where a record is moved from FromDualList to ToDualList if validation fails in GXT

```
DualListFrom.getStore().addStoreListener(
    new StoreListener<Model>() {
       @Override
      public void storeRemove( StoreEvent<Model> se ) {            
        if(!validation){

          se.setCancelled( true ); // this doesnt cancel the event
        }
       }
    }
    );
```

But `se.setCancelled( true );` doesnt prevent moving the record from fromList to ToList.